# Is Gremsy Mio gimbal compatible with DJI matrice 100 UAV?

Tags: dji, gimbal

Is Gremsy Mio gimbal compatible with DJI matrice 100 UAV?

Link to gimbal part: https://gremsy.com/mio

Link to UAV part: https://www.dji.com/gr/matrice100